# Javascript - private array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im struggling with something quite simply in javascript.  I want to have an array which is modifiable only through methods of an object.  Consider the following example:

```
var Cart = function() {
    this.items = [];
}

Cart.prototype.getItems = function() {
    return this.items;
}

Cart.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
}

module.exports = Cart;
```

I want to be able to add new items through the addItem method and to retrieve the items through the getItems method.  I dont want to be able to just do Cart.items.push(item) for example.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Prototype will not help in this case... it requires you to make your properties public. A self contained function with a scope variable can do the thrick

Comment: Yes, this might give you an idea: http://philipwalton.com/articles/implementing-private-and-protected-members-in-javascript/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can achieve that functionality by leveraging the `scope` of your constructor.

Instead of defining the array as a public property, you define it as a variable:

```
var Cart = function() {
    var items = [];

    this.getItems = function() {
        return items;
    }

    this.addItem = function(item) {
        items.push(item);
    }

    this.addAndRetrieve = function(item) {
        items.push(item);
        return items;
    }
}

module.exports = Cart;
```

Then, you can access it through the publicly exposed methods `getItems` and `addItem`

```
var x = new Cart(),
    y = new Cart();

x.addItem(1);
y.addItem(2);

x.getItems(); // [1]
y.getItems(); // [2]
```

**EDIT1**: If these are the only 2 methods that you want to chain on your instance, you can simply combine them in a new function and achieve the combined functionality.

Comment: But you can then do x.getItems().push(1) couldnt you?

Comment: No, you can't chain methods by using this pattern.

Comment: I just tried it in the console (removing the module.exports line so it works).

you can absolutely do x.getItems().push(1);

x.getItems() returns the reference to the list which you can then access.

this also works.
```var x = new Cart();
var items = x.getItems(); // []
items.push('foo');
x.getItems(); // ['foo']
```

Edit: formatting a comment is hard :(

Comment: Downvoted because array is not private in any useful sense.

Answer (score 2):

With ES6 [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) you can do it like this:

```
var items = new WeakMap();

var Cart = function() {
  items[this] = [];
};

Cart.prototype.getItems = function() {
  return items[this];
};

Cart.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
  items[this].push(item);
};

module.exports = Cart;
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you don't have private properties. Here are some options:

1 - call property `_items`. That's a well known convention for naming private properties;

2 - use closure:

```
var Cart = function() {
  var items = [];

  this.getItems = function() {
    return items;
  };

 this.addItem = function(item) {
    items.push(item);
 };    

}
```

3 - use symbols. They are not truly private, but hard to discover:

```
var items = Symbol();
var Cart = function() {
    this[items] = [];
}

Cart.prototype.getItems = function() {
    return this[items];
}

Cart.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
    this[items].push(item);
}
```

4 - use [private-symbol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/private-symbol) module instead. This will work only in node.js/io.js (uses v8 C++ API), but gives you truly private symbols

5 - use `WeakMap`

```
var items = new WeakMap();
var Cart = function() {
    items.set(this, []);
}

Cart.prototype.getItems = function() {
    return items.get(this);
}

Cart.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
    items.get(this).push(item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Will this meet your requirements?

```
var Cart = function() {
    var items = [];

    this.getItems = function() {
        return items;
    };

    this.addItem = function(item) {
        items.push(item);
    };
}
```